# Wine/Proton: unable to stat out-file from Z: drive, possibly permissions?

Tags: wine

I'm getting the following error while trying to launch a Wine application.

```
[DISPLAY] (path: Z:\home\myuser\.local\share\somepath\file.exe cmdline: "Z:\home\myuser\.local\share\somepath\file.exe")
[2018-09-16 21:25:23.807] [DISPLAY] exited with code 0xc0000005
[ ERROR ] Unable to stat out-file!
[ ERROR ] * Setting error condition
[ ERROR ] * Category:  5 (ERROR_CATEGORY_EXIT_CODE)
[ ERROR ] * Code:     -1073741819 (c0000005)
```

Error 5, from my knowledge, is a permission issue. To attempt to solve it I set the permission of file.exe to 777 without success. I'm not sure where to go from there other than setting the entire folder structure past "somepath" to 777.

Has anyone ever deal with a situation in which Wine was unable to access a file in the Z: drive, and what permissions you used to fix that? Maybe it has nothing to do with permissions?

To test this I also launched Notepad++ in PlayOnLinux and opened the same exe file in the editor successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, this is regarding running GTAV on Steam with Proton.

I created a file in `/home/user/.steam` and called it `gta_dxvk.conf`.

The problem I had was that when I created the file it didn't save a line break, so everything was on one line. The fixed file looks like this:

```
dxgi.customDeviceId = E366 
dxgi.customVendorId = 1002
```

You then have to add the file to the game's launch options in Steam.

```
DXVK_CONFIG_FILE=/home/user/.steam/gta_dxvk.conf
```